# What is the fastest way to texture bake a full scene?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, baking

I am familiar with the concept of baking in cycles to use it in the bge.
Can I somehow bake the whole scene without having to select one object each time?

If yes which is the fastest way so I won't have to waste a lot of time?

I don't care if the CPU will work overtime.

Comment: At least part of textures can be baked with [Texture Atlas](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/UV/TextureAtlas) addon into one image.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your intended volume either by doing it manually or making a script that handles the bake.

You will need to manage at least the following:

- texture resolution for each baked mesh object
- which objects to bake (you probably don't want to bake glass / transparent objects / illuminating surfaces / gfx like light halos etc
- setting up lightmap bake UV layer (most likely you have the default UV used for getting the texture itself tiling correctly)
- setting up an image texture node for every material in the object being baked and make a new image for it and make the node selected
- saving the texture on disk with naming convention that allows you to read the images into a new, realtime baked materials that correspond to the mesh objects when you start BGE

If you plan on making more than 1 or 2 levels, to me it definitely calls for script assistance.