# Cycles export+bake to Unreal

Tags: cycles-render-engine, export, texture-baking, unreal-engine

I am looking into the viability of a pipeline from Blender to Unreal. Here's what I want to do:

**1)** Make a Cycles scene

**2)** Bake everything to textures

**3)** Bring it into Unreal with as little work as possible.

The end goal is to have a still scene in Unreal that you can move the camera around in, but that looks like a full Cycles render.

Some of the issues that I foresee:

- Camera based effects like Fresnel won't transfer properly, so they would have to be done in Unreal instead of Cycles.
- Currently many of my textures are procedural and use Object or Generated texture coordinates. Can these be baked to UVs?

I know that I can bake a single model and it's textures out, and bring it into an unreal model viewer easily. However, I want to do full scenes that involve multiple characters, buildings, terrain, etc., with potentially hundreds of different models. I need to be able to batch bake and export/import it all.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Procedural textures aren't a problem. As for batch baking, blender does support this natively (just click bake with multiple objects selected), but for batch bake preparation (create images etc.) a little python may be required. Chances are there already [some addons](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/CyclesBatchBaker) for assisting with this.

Comment: It would require a GREAT deal of scripting. I outline some of what is needed here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51079/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-texture-bake-a-full-scene/51080#51080

Furthermore I would say baking any of the lighting in Blender for Unreal engine is totally backwards unless you're interested in completely static environment. without any of the UEs awesome PBR shaders. For moving camera and real-time shading the results are so much better when you use appropriate solutions like UE4 or Unity that also have the light baking tools integrated in them.